# POST data to a php page using curl

Tags: php, post, curl

There is a site http://www.kovansports.com/bookonline/ , and I think the page is an index.php because when I typed that filename in I do not get a 404.

In that page, there is a label 'Schedule For', where you can choose a date and press Go. The form action references back to the same page (http://www.kovansports.com/bookonline/), and presents the table associated with the new date chosen.

I am testing a PHP page to post a date to the site above, so that I get the table for the date I want, for scraping information.

The code that I used is below, and it is not working somehow, as I am faced with a 404 error. First time doing this, so please let me know what I am doing wrong and the best way to achieve my objective. Thanks!

```
<?php
$urltopost = "http://www.kovansports.com/bookonline/index.php";
$datatopost = "date=07-Aug-13&loadschedule=1";

$ch = curl_init ($urltopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
$returndata = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
print $returndata; //display the reuslt
?>
```

Comment: That isn't the url the form goes to, and they aren't the values sent in the form post, you can use something like chrome developer tools (f12) or firefox + firebug to find out what you need to send and where you need to send it

Comment: Remove `index.php` and give it a try. The server could be using .htaccess for nice uris.

Comment: _I think the page is an index.php because when I typed that filename in I do not get a 404._ You think bad, when you type this you get a 301 on http://www.kovansports.com/bookonline/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$urltopost = "http://www.kovansports.com/bookonline/";
```

Works fine without the index.php. They're probably using a .htaccess file to rewrite the URL.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I had to mention about my newbie assumption, but apparently I overthunk! Must be too simple for you, but very fast and very helpful to me.